# dynamic table view goto out of the frame height in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView.tag == 101)
    {
        tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y, tableView.frame.size.width, RowHeight * [lettersArray count]);
    }    
    if (tableView.tag == 201)
    {
        NSLog(@"table Height is %f",RowHeight*[selectedCategoryArray count]);
        tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y, tableView.frame.size.width, RowHeight * [selectedCategoryArray count]);
    }
    if (tableView.tag == 301)
    {
         NSLog(@"selectedSubCategoryArray count is %d",[selectedSubCategoryArray count]);
         tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y, tableView.frame.size.width, RowHeight * [selectedSubCategoryArray count]);      
    }

    return  RowHeight;
}
```

I write the code like this. But third table will display out of the height.

Comment: What do you mean of "out of the height", do you mean: a) It is to large, b) it is doesn't start at the correct location? Also, just to be sure, you are using `RowHeight` yet it has not been assigned anywhere.